# Add files from HTML input file in individual HTML table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file, html-table

I have an input="file" that allows me to select multiple files.
I'd like to have each of the files, without the extension, show in a new table row in an html table I have created.

I have the following code which allows me to find the filenames of the files selected in the `input="file"`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input[type="file"]').change(function(e){

                var files = $('#fileholder').prop("files")
                var names = $.map(files, function(val) { return val.name; });

               alert(names);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Please keep in mind I am a beginner in jQuery but may understand most of the code.

Answer (score 1):

In vanilla you could write it like this

(*JavaScript* must be invoked after *Elements* exist)

```js
var file_input = document.getElementById('file_input'),
    file_table = document.getElementById('file_table');
    
file_input.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    var i, j, fn;
    // empty table
    while (file_table.rows.length > 0)
        file_table.deleteRow(file_table.rows.length - 1);
    // add new values
    for (i = 0; i < this.files.length; ++i) {
        j = this.files[i].name.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (j > 0)
            fn = this.files[i].name.slice(0, j);
        else
            fn = this.files[i].name;
        file_table.insertRow().insertCell().textContent = fn;
    }
});
```

```html
<input id="file_input" type="file" multiple/>

<table id="file_table">
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Related documentation

- [`table.insertRow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow), [`table.deleteRow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/deleteRow)
- [`tr.insertCell`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell)
- [`input.files`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList), [`file`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)
- [`node.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [`node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Comment: The `lastIndexOf > 0` test is to permit files such as `.htaccess` showing up, where _lastIndexOf_ gives `0`. If _indexOf_ finds nothing, the return value is `-1`

Answer (score 0):

JQuery solution looks like that:

```
$('#fileholder').change(function(e){
    var files = $('#fileholder').prop("files")
    var names = $.map(files, function(val) { return val.name; });
    $.each(names, function(index){
      $('#names').append('<tr><td>'+names[index].split('.').slice(0,-1).join('.')+'</td></tr>');
    });
});
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/0gebxudp/4/**

Comment: Thanks this works. I've changed it so it splits only at .mp3 . How could I make it split at other extensions such as .m4a and .wav ?

Comment: .split('.').shift() this covers all extensions

Comment: @Piort Korlaga Yes but the problem is some music files are named such as Example Song Name (ft. Artist). By using your method anything after the ft. is removed.